# Function eregi() is deprecated

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, eregi

Function eregi() is deprecated. How can i replace eregi(). I try with preg_match but then stop working.

i us ethis help:

http://takien.com/513/how-to-fix-function-eregi-is-deprecated-in-php-5-3-0.php

CODE BEFORE:

```
if ( ! eregi("convert$", $this->library_path))
        {
            if ( ! eregi("/$", $this->library_path)) $this->library_path .= "/";

            $this->library_path .= 'convert';
        }

if (eregi("gd2$", $protocol))
        {
            $protocol = 'image_process_gd';
        }
```

CODE THEN:

```
if ( ! preg_match("convert$/i", $this->library_path))
        {
            if ( ! preg_match("/$/i", $this->library_path)) $this->library_path .= "/";

            $this->library_path .= 'convert';
        }

if (preg_match("gd2$/i", $protocol))
        {
            $protocol = 'image_process_gd';
        }
```

Comment: PHP is moving toward PCRE extension : http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`preg_match` expects its regex argument to be within a pair delimiters.

So try:

```
if ( ! preg_match("#convert$#i", $this->library_path)) {
        if ( ! preg_match("#/$#i", $this->library_path)) 
                $this->library_path .= "/";

        $this->library_path .= 'convert';
}

if (preg_match("#gd2$#i", $protocol)) {                                         
        $protocol = 'image_process_gd'; 
}
```

Comment: No need for this particular task to be completed with regular expressions..,

Answer (score 2):

It seems you just forgot the Delimiter

```
preg_match("~/$~", $this->library_path)
```

and

```
preg_match("~gd2$~i", $protocol)
```

But in both cases you should consider not using regular expressions, because they are oversized here

```
$this->library_path[strlen($this->library_path) - 1] == '/'
substr($protocol, -3) == 'gd2'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just checking for the presence of one string inside another, you should just use the [`strpos()`](http://uk.php.net/strpos) function. eg:

```
if(strpos('convert', $this->library_path) !== false) {
    // code here
}
```

**Update:** Misread you want to check for it at the END of a string, this is still possible without Regex by using [`substr()`](https://www.php.net/substr):

```
if(substr($this->library_path, -7) == 'convert'  {
    //code here
}
```

Where `7` is the length of convert, you could use a strlen and subtract it from 0 to get this number dynamically.
This won't start any regex so is much more efficient.