# Warning: function eregi() is deprecated

Tags: php, contact-form

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Function eregi() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700806/function-eregi-is-deprecated)

I have created a contact form with PHP, but am getting a warning:

> Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\hosting\9606426\html\Websites\LuxeBeauty\1\contact.php on line 9

This is line 9:

```
if(!eregi("^[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*" ."@"."([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+"."\\.[a-
z]{2,}"."$",$email )){
    ...
}
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: What have you tried? Dumping all your code here means _"Debug this for me"_, which is not the way things work here. Try searching the web on the warning you get and see which methods are recommended.

Comment: Perhaps RTFM? It's all explained here: http://php.net/eregi

Comment: use preg instead, just like it says in the manual. Or use the filtering functionality

Answer (score 5, accepted):

eregi has been depreciated, which means that you'll need to switch to:

```
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $error.="Invalid email address entered";
    $errors=1;
}
```

Comment: +1 for not using a regex for email validation.

Comment: @CodeCaster I tried my best to get this in before the wave of preg_match examples!

Comment: to me the original code I pasted seems far too complicated. I usually don't bother with echoing text, instead just send to a URL, one saying success, other saying OOps (or something like that). But this particular client asked for it to come up there and then...

Comment: As its a template, i have little clue what parts of the full PHP do... Looking at line 9, am I right that all it does is check that an email address is valid? I.E. has an @ sign in it, and only certain characters?

Comment: OOH and that did the trick perfectly... Sorry for my ignorance, I don't use this site much, only now an then for weird bugs. I am an IT Consultant usually with network systems etc, not a designer and not a developer usually haha... Thanks for all your help tho. ^^ Question above still stands though... ^^^

Comment: As of PHP 5.3.3, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL is based on this blog post by Michael Rushton: http://squiloople.com/2009/12/20/email-address-validation/