# Deprecated: Function eregi()

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Function eregi() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700806/function-eregi-is-deprecated)

Hello I am getting this error

Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in /home/u578804202/public_html/includes/functions.php on line 4

Here is my code:

```
if(eregi($file,$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    die("Sorry but you cannot access this file directly for security reasons.");
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: I'm going to put it out there, you might be getting the "function is deprecated" warning because the function it mentions is deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you should, it's an old function that is deprecated, user `stristr()` instead

```
if(stristr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],$file)) {
    die("Sorry but you cannot access this file directly for security reasons.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `preg_match` instead:

```
if (!preg_match("~{$file}~i,", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    die("Sorry but you cannot access this file directly for security reasons.");
}
```