# Converting specific eregi function to preg_match

Tags: preg-match, deprecated, eregi

I have read all the questions and answers here and am having trouble converting the following depricated eregi function

```
for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($this->browser_languages); $i<$n; $i++) {
    reset($this->languages);
    while (list($key, $value) = each($this->languages)) {
      if (eregi ("^(" . $value . ")(;q=[0-9]\\.[0-9])?$",      $this->browser_languages[$i]) && isset($this->catalog_languages[$key])) {
        $this->language = $this->catalog_languages[$key];
        break 2;
      }
    }
```

Can someone please help me figure this out.  I have tried some things already but nothing seems to work.  Thank you for any help

bbg

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function eregi() is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700806/function-eregi-is-deprecated)

Comment: There is no difficulty here : just add / at the beginning and the end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)